# What is a word or phrase for something that, though it ought to be unbelievable, you can believe is actually true?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

An example would be President Trump's tweets where when you're told about them your first instinct is to believe that can't possibly have been tweeted. But you nevertheless accept that it probably did happen.

> **Me:** Can you believe Trump tweeted about eating his boogers?
> **You:** At this point, yeah. Yeah I can.

Comment: "If it weren't 2020 I wouldn't believe it."

Comment: Please give a phrase with the word you're looking for left blank.

Answer (score 2):

"It beggars belief."

> **beggar belief​** [phrase]
>
> used for expressing shock at something that is extremely difficult to
> believe or describe
>
> - *His attitude simply beggars belief!*

[[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/beggar-belief-description)]

Obviously, the shock at observing the event or state entails that the event etc is actually real.

As other dictionaries state, this can also be used of totally unbelievable claims or theories, and is more common in the UK than the US.

........

A noun for an [almost] unbelievable event (usually one with good results) is, of course, a **miracle**. But we often use "Unbelievable!" "Incredible!" and so on with the watered-down "I can ***hardly*** believe it!" sense.

Comment: I feel like it misses something. Yes there is an expression of disbelief but there is, simultaneously, an almost dejected total belief in the likelihood of the event.

Answer (score 1):

I think the adverb *incredibly* fits your bill.  I cannot prove it, but I think that this word,  as first word in a declaratory  sentence, does have a strongly concessive force, meaning something like:

> Though I can hardly believe I'm saying this, ....

So let us suppose that Putin makes a statement that he did not want to chang the result of the US election of 2016.  I could say:

> Incredibly, I believe him.

My reason my be that I think he does not care who wins the election but just seeks to undermine the electorate's confidence in democracy.

Comment: It's more than that. I'm looking for the sense that you wouldn't have rationally considered the thing to be a likelihood or that it could be real; that what was once incredible is now completely credible. What do you call the state of being where what could reasonably be thought of as fiction is now regularly non-fiction?

Comment: @Kristopher You mean like black holes? Or, going back further, the big bang?  Or, nearer the knuckle, a game show host being elected president of a major world power?

Comment: @Kristopher: The latter is known as *life imitates art*

Answer (score 0):

### Anything goes.

Anything can happen; there are no rules.  See the musical and the Cole Porter lyrics starting with, "Times have changed..."

> In olden days, a glimpse of stocking
>
>  Was looked on as something shocking.
>
> But now, God knows,
>
> **Anything goes.**

These lyrics in particular resonate with your example about current events:

> Just think of those shocks you've got
>
> And those knocks you've got
>
> And those blues you've got
>
> From that news you've got
>
> And those pains you've got
>
> (If any brains you've got)
>
> From those little radios.

To express disbelief, I might also say:

- "What next?"
- "Will wonders never cease?"
- "The mind boggles."
- "Stranger things have happened."

From literature, there's **"Curiouser and curiouser!"** Cried Alice (she was so much surprised, that for the moment she quite forgot how to speak good English)." Lewis Carroll, *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*

**"There are more things in heaven and earth**, Horatio, than are dreamt of in your philosophy.” Shakespeare, *Hamlet*

Comment: But what is the word for something having been previously unbelievable but is now regularly believable?

Comment: Hm, @Kristopher what synonyms of unbelievable didn't work for you?  Please write a fill-in-the-blank sentence for your question if you are looking for a single word, and I suggest you list what you've ruled out.